# Couldn't use options property of ion-slides

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-slides

I have created a new app using Ionic v4 and tried adding slides to my app but I get an error stating

```
Can't bind to 'options' since it isn't a known property of 'ion-slides'
```

The html is

```html
<ion-content padding>
   <ion-slides [options]="slideOpts">
      <ion-slide>
         <h1>Slide 1</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
         <h1>Slide 2</h1>
      </ion-slide>
      <ion-slide>
         <h1>Slide 3</h1>
      </ion-slide>
   </ion-slides>
</ion-content>
```

My Ts is

```js
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

   slideOpts = {
      initialSlide: 1,
      speed: 400
   };

   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
   }
}
```

However the same worked for me in Ionic v3. Could anyone please help me out?

Comment: Could you add your - cmd `ionic info` I can't replicate your problem in my project

Comment: @IraJW could you please try using ionic v4

Comment: according to your import (ionic-angular) you are using v3. You need to ensure you have v4 installed and do imports from proper locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.. its working fine ionic 4.0.0

```
 import { IonSlides } from '@ionic/angular';

    @Component({
      selector: 'page-home',
      templateUrl: 'home.html'
    })
    export class HomePage {
    @ViewChild(IonSlides) slides: IonSlides;
      slideOpts = {
        initialSlide: 1,
        speed: 400
      };

      constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      }
     ngOnInit() {  this.slideOpts = {
        initialSlide: 1,
        speed: 400
      };
    }
    }
```

Comment: I couldn't find the module @ionic/angular

Comment: your ionic exact version ??

Comment: The ionic version I am using is  v4.4.0

Comment: I used ionic version 4.0.0

Comment: Thanks alot it worked by the way I installed @ionic/angular manually to my project

Comment: Great Effort @naveenashok

Answer (score 0):

Just laying my point here, especially for new people like me, so i'll try to go slow.

Assuming SlideComponent is an independant component like [Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcUj9.png)

You already have a components.module.ts to export all components created in the components folder.

Here's how components.module.ts will look like:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SlidesComponent } from './slides/slides.component';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular'; //import



@NgModule({
  declarations: [SlidesComponent,],
  exports:[SlidesComponent, /*feel free to add any additional component*/],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    IonicModule //add
  ]
})
export class ComponentsModule { }
```

PS: this works on Ionic V 6.5

Comment: Could to please take a look into the question one more time.